Why does my alert modal from ShadCn close immediately after i click it?
I created an action wherein it will show a menu, and I have a function wherein if the user choose to delete, it will show an alert warning first before continuing, but the problem I'm encountering right now is when I click the menu, the modal will open but immediately close. I was guessing it closes because the menu close after it was clicked.
import Image from 'next/image';
import {
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownMenuContent,
  DropdownMenuItem,
  DropdownMenuLabel,
  DropdownMenuSeparator,
  DropdownMenuTrigger,
} from '@/components/ui/dropdown-menu';
import { Trash2 } from 'lucide-react';
import {
  AlertDialog,
  AlertDialogAction,
  AlertDialogCancel,
  AlertDialogContent,
  AlertDialogDescription,
  AlertDialogFooter,
  AlertDialogHeader,
  AlertDialogTitle,
  AlertDialogTrigger,
} from '@/components/ui/alert-dialog';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <DropdownMenu>
        <DropdownMenuTrigger>Open</DropdownMenuTrigger>
        <DropdownMenuContent>
          <DropdownMenuLabel>My Account</DropdownMenuLabel>
          <DropdownMenuSeparator />
          <DropdownMenuItem>
            <Trash2 className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" />
            <AlertDialog>
              <AlertDialogTrigger>Open</AlertDialogTrigger>
              <AlertDialogContent>
                <AlertDialogHeader>
                  <AlertDialogTitle>Are you absolutely sure?</AlertDialogTitle>
                  <AlertDialogDescription>
                    This action cannot be undone. This will permanently delete
                    your account and remove your data from our servers.
                  </AlertDialogDescription>
                </AlertDialogHeader>
                <AlertDialogFooter>
                  <AlertDialogCancel>Cancel</AlertDialogCancel>
                  <AlertDialogAction>Continue</AlertDialogAction>
                </AlertDialogFooter>
              </AlertDialogContent>
            </AlertDialog>
          </DropdownMenuItem>
        </DropdownMenuContent>
      </DropdownMenu>
    </div>
  );
}


I created a sample , actual sample

The reason is does not work: you dialog content is defined inside menu item. when you click on menu item it render dialog for a split second, but them menu is being removed from DOM and dialog content as it's child being removed form the DOM as well.
The simplest way to fix this in your case is to wrap menu item in alert dialog and move dialog content from menu item, like this:
import {
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownMenuContent,
  DropdownMenuItem,
  DropdownMenuLabel,
  DropdownMenuSeparator,
  DropdownMenuTrigger,
} from '@/components/ui/dropdown-menu';
import { Trash2 } from 'lucide-react';
import {
  AlertDialog,
  AlertDialogAction,
  AlertDialogCancel,
  AlertDialogContent,
  AlertDialogDescription,
  AlertDialogFooter,
  AlertDialogHeader,
  AlertDialogTitle,
  AlertDialogTrigger,
} from '@/components/ui/alert-dialog';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <AlertDialog>
        <DropdownMenu>
          <DropdownMenuTrigger>Open</DropdownMenuTrigger>
          <DropdownMenuContent>
            <DropdownMenuLabel>My Account</DropdownMenuLabel>
            <DropdownMenuSeparator />
            <DropdownMenuItem>
              <Trash2 className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" />
              <AlertDialogTrigger>Open</AlertDialogTrigger>
            </DropdownMenuItem>
          </DropdownMenuContent>
        </DropdownMenu>
        <AlertDialogContent>
          <AlertDialogHeader>
            <AlertDialogTitle>Are you absolutely sure?</AlertDialogTitle>
            <AlertDialogDescription>
              This action cannot be undone. This will permanently delete your
              account and remove your data from our servers.
            </AlertDialogDescription>
          </AlertDialogHeader>
          <AlertDialogFooter>
            <AlertDialogCancel>Cancel</AlertDialogCancel>
            <AlertDialogAction>Continue</AlertDialogAction>
          </AlertDialogFooter>
        </AlertDialogContent>
      </AlertDialog>
    </div>
  );
}

